# assigning object value after dictionary key

Tags: python

I have seen this piece of code that looks for `regex` expressions in a string and returns valid or not valid. I do understand the `regex` but I don't understand how one specific part works:

```
import re

checks = {
  "alpha"     : lambda uid: re.match(r".*[A-Z].*[A-Z].*", uid),
  "num"       : lambda uid: re.match(r".*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*", uid),
  "alpha_num" : lambda uid: re.match(r"[A-Za-z0-9]{10}", uid),
  "repeat"    : lambda uid: not re.match(r".*(.).*\1.*", uid)
}

def main():
  for _ in range(int(input())):
    uid = input()
    print("Valid" if all(checks[check](uid) for check in checks.keys()) else "Invalid")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

This is the part I don't understand:

```
checks[check](uid)
```

How is it possible to have a dictionary which is `checks` followed by a key which is `check` followed by a string input which is `uid` ? `checks[check]` makes sense to me but not `checks[check](uid)`

Comment: Because `checks[check]` is a _function_, that's what all the `lambda`s are doing.

Comment: function ? thought `checks[check]` is a dictionary with the key which is being iterated

Comment: `checks` is a dictionary. `checks[check]` is a _value_ from that dictionary, because `check` is a _key_ from that dictionary.

Comment: That code is equivalent to `all(check(uid) for check in checks.values())`. Does that make it more obvious?

Comment: Remember that a function is an object just like other Python objects.  `checks[check]` returns an element from the dictionary.  That element happens to be a function.  `checks[check](uid)` is just like `func(uid)`, we just get the function object in a different way.

Comment: oh ok, I got confused since lambda is an anonymous function. but it seems like you can still call it this way